# How does JSPM deal with CSS files?

Tags: css, gruntjs, bower, jspm, wiredep

I've been using bower for a while combined with wiredep but I want to switch to using the System.js loader. For this, JSPM is ideal. However, one of the things the combination of bower and wiredep was doing for me was also including the (S)CSS.

Does JSPM deal with these files at all? Or is there a different approach that I should take to also deal with those files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`jspm install css`

there is a plugin for this :)

for more infomation:  https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-css

---

update: also, as @Ron said:

> use it as `<script>System.import('packageName/package.css!')</script>`

Comment: Then use it as: <script>System.import('packageName/package.css!')</script>

Comment: @Ron They really need to add that to their docs. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jspm` it's convenient to add this settings to `jspm` related config.js file

```
System.config({
  meta: {
    '*.css': { loader: 'css' }
  },
...
}
```

so you don't need to add a suffix `!css` each time you import css file

Comment: i add this config but i still need to add '!' to import css file